# Handling exceptions while getting data when its possible

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, task-parallel-library, task

Below is the code I am using to retrieve data from several urls. For couple of urls I get exception but for all others I do get valid data. Problem is that with apporoach below, I am not able to collect data for threads that were able to retrieve data without any issue. Is there anyway to collect as much url response while also knowing which urls throw exceptions?

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var URLsToProcess = new List<string>
            {
                "http://www.microsoft.com",
                "http://www.stackoverflow.com",
                "http://www.google.com",
                "http://www.apple.com",
                "http://www.ebay.com",
                "http://www.oracle.com",
                "http://www.gmail.com",
                "http://www.amazon.com",
                "http://www.outlook.com",
                "http://www.yahoo.com",
                "http://www.amazon124.com",
                "http://www.msn.com"
                };

    string[] tURLs = null;
    try
    {
        tURLs = URLsToProcess
            .AsParallel()
            .WithDegreeOfParallelism(3)
            .Select(uri => DownloadStringAsTask(new Uri(uri)).Result)
            .ToArray();
    }
    catch (AggregateException ex)
    {
        AggregateException exf =  ex.Flatten();

    }
    Console.WriteLine("download all done");
    if (tURLs != null)
    {
        foreach (string t in tURLs)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(t);
        }
    }
}

static Task<string> DownloadStringAsTask(Uri address)
{
    TaskCompletionSource<string> tcs =
      new TaskCompletionSource<string>();
    WebClient client = new WebClient();
    client.DownloadStringCompleted += (sender, args) =>
    {
        if (args.Error != null) 
            tcs.SetException(args.Error);
        else if (args.Cancelled) 
            tcs.SetCanceled();
        else 
            tcs.SetResult(args.Result);
    };
    client.DownloadStringAsync(address);
    return tcs.Task;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there is:

```
var tasks = URLsToProcess.Select(uri => DownloadStringAsTask(new Uri(uri))).ToArray();

while (tasks.Any())
{
    try
    {
        Task.WaitAll(tasks);
        break;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        // handle exception/report progress...
        tasks = tasks.Where(t => t.Status != TaskStatus.Faulted).ToArray();
    }
}

var results = tasks.Select(t => t.Result);
```

Use `Task.WaitAll` to wait (synchronously since `async-await` isn't available) for all the tasks concurrently to complete. If `Task.WaitAll` completes successfully, break out of the `while` loop and extract the results using `Task.Result`. If there's an exception remove the faulted task and wait again for the other task and so forth.

Comment: Not sure if I should post a new question but can you change your example so that I start getting progress on which tasks have completed while others are still in progress and some have thrown exception?

Comment: @johnsmith You should post a different question. You can link it here though and I'll take a look.

Comment: thanks for your continued help but it seem like there is an infinite loop when its going in the catch block

Comment: yes sir. Not sure if its possible but you can run the code to see for yourself

Comment: I can post the whole new code in my question if you want to try it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67933/discussion-between-i3arnon-and-john-smith).